# Execute method via breakpoint

Tags: android, debugging, breakpoints

How does one call a method, whilst a breakpoint is active within a running debug application?

I have a GSON object, that is writing JSON data to a text file, I wish to breakpoint the application and execute that method manually.

Comment: are you trying to execute a method automatically when a breakpoint is hit?

Comment: No the method is else where, but I want to breakpoint somewhere else, because that method cant be called automatically

Comment: I cant understand your question, please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are searching should be called "Evaluate Expression".

The normal shortcut is alt+f8.